# delete list from multiple nested list

Tags: python, list, dataframe

```
`DATA=[('MY NAME IS SAM MY AGE IS 25,
  'labels:',
  [-1, 2, 'ACCOUNT BALANCE'],
  [-1, 2, 'NAME'],
  [48, 55, 'XYZ']),
 ('i AM AHMAD MY AGE IS 41',
  'labels:',
  [-1, 2, 'ACCOUNT BALANCE'],
  [-1, 2, 'ABC'],
  [48, 55, 'VSG']),
 ('MY NAME IS KATE ',
  'labels:',
  [-1, 2, 'ABC'],
  [-1, 2, 'DEF'],
  [48, 55, 'GHI'])`
```

In the following example I want to delete all the list that contains -1, 2 e.g. [-1, 2, 'ACCOUNT BALANCE'], [-1, 2, 'DEF']

`EXDATA = [i for i in DATA if i and (-1 not in i)]`

I was trying this but not working
I was expecting this

`[('MY NAME IS SAM MY AGE IS 25, 'labels:', [48, 55, 'XYZ']), ('i AM AHMAD MY AGE IS 41', 'labels:', [48, 55, 'VSG']), ('MY NAME IS KATE ', 'labels:',, [48, 55, 'GHI'])`

Comment: You have to write (or find with Google) a function to search recursively in sublists of the tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after the data list is defined in your code:

```
EXDATA = [i for i in DATA if not any(j == [-1, 2] for j in i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix the input data structure to match brackets and remove quotes.

This solution does a nested list search selecting only inner elements that don't have a -1. This works well for lists, but as you have tuples mixed with lists in your data structure it returns all as lists. I guess you could use a tuple generator if you wanted to keep tuples in the mix.

```
DATA=[('MY NAME IS SAM MY AGE IS 25',
       'labels:',
       [-1, 2, 'ACCOUNT BALANCE'],
       [-1, 2, 'NAME'],
       [48, 55, 'XYZ']),
      ('i AM AHMAD MY AGE IS 41',
       'labels:',
       [-1, 2, 'ACCOUNT BALANCE'],
       [-1, 2, 'ABC'],
       [48, 55, 'VSG']),
      ('MY NAME IS KATE ',
       'labels:',
       [-1, 2, 'ABC'],
       [-1, 2, 'DEF'],
       [48, 55, 'GHI'])
     ]

EXDATA = [[j for j in i if all(k!=-1 for k in j)] for i in DATA]
```

With the output:

```
[['MY NAME IS SAM MY AGE IS 25', 'labels:', [48, 55, 'XYZ']],
 ['i AM AHMAD MY AGE IS 41', 'labels:', [48, 55, 'VSG']],
 ['MY NAME IS KATE ', 'labels:', [48, 55, 'GHI']]]
```